# Segment voice and unvoiced speech?

Tags: audio, signals, signal-processing, speech

I'd like to know how can I do a phonetic segmention of an audio file. 
E.g. Father, I think it'd be, F-a-th-er.

I tought about using Zero Crossing to detect the Voiced and Unvoiced Region but I'm know sure about it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zero-crossing you mentioned is one way to go, as explained e.g. in [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5395954/) article. Other include neural networks or Hidden Markov Models.

To get any decent results, you should also have a language model. It's much easier to work with sentences / words and only then translate these into phonemes. Why? Because context is essential for computer systems - and often even us, humans - to understand the word. Context provides constraints for phonemes and it's hard (impossible?) to work without it.

Comment: thank you for your answer. 
What do you mean by language model?

Comment: Consider English, Polish and Chinese. Sounds will be vastly different and so the words that make sense. Take also for instance HMM. With good priors, you can more easily (=less data) achieve nice results.

Comment: It is my understanding that HMM have 3 main features, the definition of states (in this case 1 - voiced and 2 - unvoiced, the initial state and the hidden states. Right?   
What are the hidden state when it comes to distinguish voiced and unvoiced? And the initial state?